# I have both Login And Register form Inside a tab content. So the Problem Is That I can set action for any one form. How can I sove it

Tags: php, forms

```
<form id=reg_form action="includes/data.inc.php" method="POST">
<div class="login-modal-right">

<!-- Login Form -->

<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="login" role="tabpanel">
<h5 class="heading-design-h5">Login to your account</h5>
<fieldset class="form-group">
<label>Enter Email/Mobile number</label>
<input type="text" name="email_num" class="form-control" placeholder="123 456 7890" required>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="form-group">
<label>Enter Password</label>
<input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="********" required>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="form-group">
<button type="submit" name="login-submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary btn-block">Enter My Account</button>
</fieldset>
</div>

<!-- Register Form -->

<div class="tab-pane" id="register" role="tabpanel">
<h5 class="heading-design-h5">Register Now!</h5>
<fieldset class="form-group">
<label for="reg-name">Full Name</label>
<input type="text" name="fullname" id="reg-name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Full Name" required>
</fieldset>
<p id="namechk"></p>
<fieldset class="form-group">
<label for="reg-email">Enter Email</label>
<input type="email" name="email" id="reg-email" class="form-control" placeholder="example@gmail.com" required>
</fieldset>
<p id="emailchk"></p>
<fieldset class="form-group">
<label for="reg-num">Enter Mobile Number</label>
<input type="text" name="number" id="reg-num" class="form-control" placeholder="123 456 7890" required>
</fieldset>
<p id="numchk"></p>
<fieldset class="form-group">
<label for="reg-pass">Enter Password</label>
<input type="password" name="pass" id="reg-pass" class="form-control" placeholder="********" required>
</fieldset>
<p id="passchk"></p>
<!-- <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
<label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck2">I Agree with <a href="#">Term and Conditions</a></label>
</div> -->
<fieldset class="form-group">
<input type="submit" id="reg-sub" value="Create Your Account" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary btn-block" role="button">
</fieldset>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="text-center login-footer-tab">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#login" role="tab"><i class="mdi mdi-lock"></i> LOGIN</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#register" role="tab"><i class="mdi mdi-pencil"></i> REGISTER</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
</form>
```

The Problem Is I can only set an action for any one form. Let say if I set the action for the registration form then where or how I can set the action for the login form. I have even tried separating them, but it actually breaks the design. If anyone can resolve it with design (Just in case if I did any error) then you are most welcome. Or if there's any way I can set action for both of them separately. I do tried manipulating both of them from the same page(action page) but again it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Put separate form tag for each tab

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="login" role="tabpanel">
<form>
</form>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane" id="register" role="tabpanel">
<form>
</form>
</div>
```